# Solidworks Simulation- Large displacement with Inertia Relief

Tags: finite-element-method, simulation, solidworks

I'm trying to use the Solidworks simulation package to solve for the stresses inside a body as it accelerates (very rapidly). Because I expect some small features to deform quite a bit, I need to use the large displacement option, but because the object translates through space, I need to solve it using the inertia relief option. When I start the simulation with both option checked, I get the error message:

*Inertia Relief with Iterative solver is not supported by Large Displacement. Please use the Direct Sparse Solver.*

At the conceptual/math level, why can't I use both the Large Displacement option and the Inertia Relief option with the default FFEPlus solver?